# Value_Counts, Mapping, GroupBy and Plotting

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, mapping

I am working on a personal project using IMDB Data and have currently exhausted all avenues.

Quick Overview:

- I am trying to find the top 10 grossing Directors and Actors
- I can do this but would like to take it one step further and only find the top 10 if they have met certain criteria. EG: Have starred in > 4 Films

So far, I have executed the following:

```
plt.subplot2grid((2,3),(0,1))
actor_1 = df.pivot_table(index="Actor_1", values="Gross_Earnings", aggfunc='sum').sort_values(ascending=False)
actor_1[:15].sort_values(ascending=True).plot(kind='barh', width=0.7, alpha=0.5, color='red')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=60)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=60)
plt.xlabel("Gross Earnings")
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

This works, but it only returns the top values; not the top values with the additional criteria of > 4 Films.

I have also tried the following:

```
no_of_films = df.groupby("Actor_1")
name_count_key = df["Actor_1"].value_counts().to_dict()
no_of_films["Films"] = no_of_films["Actor_1"].map(name_count_key)
```

But it returns the following error: "AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'map' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

```
no_of_films = df.groupby("Actor_1")
name_count_key = df["Actor_1"].value_counts().to_dict()
no_of_films["Films"] = no_of_films["Actor_1"].apply(name_count_key)
```

But it returns the following error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'"

The group-by function idea was to create a new column called "Films" so count the volume of Films each actor has starred in and then use > 4 but it returns bools and not the actual value.

```
Director        Actor_1         IMDB_Score   Gross_Earnings    Movie_Title
Andrew Stanton  Daryl Sabara    6.6          73058679          John Carter
Sam Raimi       J.K. Simmons    6.2          336530303         Spider-Man 3
Nathan Greno    Brad Garrett    7.8          200807262         Tangled
Joss Whedon     Chris Hemsworth 7.5          458991599         Avengers: Age of Ultron
```

Is this possible or am I being silly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: It seems you need `df["Films"] = df["Actor_1"].map(name_count_key)`, can you give some data sample?

Comment: I created a new data frame "no_of_films" so I group actors who starred in multiple films. The map function works on the original data frame, but when summing up the value counts, it counts the sum (multiplied by the number of appearances which is incorrect)

Comment: Withoud data is is not easy answer. Small advice - [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: try past samples with `4 spaces` first in each line like your code.

Comment: Apologies - I wasn't aware that posting images were frowned upon. Essentially, the data frame as multiple columns. Director, Actor_1, IMDB_Score, Gross_Earnings and Movie_Title. EG: Johnny Depp has starred in more than 4 films so I would like to return his median IMDB Score for all his films. Currently, actors that have only starred in one film is skewing the data (IE: they could have one really good film) and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think better is add to question first 5 rows from picture. Is it possible?

Comment: I have added the first three lines to the question. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: thank you. So need count names of `Actor_1`s and if more as `4` do you need filter, right?

Comment: Yes - In addition to gross earnings, I would like to see the average "IMDB_Score" for actors that have starred in more than four films and then plot the top 15 actors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
print (df)
            Director          Actor_1  IMDB_Score  Gross_Earnings Movie_Title
0      James Cameron      CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847      Avatar
1      James Cameron      CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar1
2      James Cameron      CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar2
3      James Cameron      CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar3
4     Gore Verbinski      Johnny Depp         7.1       309404152     Pirates
5         Sam Mendes  Christoph Waltz         6.8       200074175     Spectre
6     Gore Verbinski      Johnny Depp         7.1       309404152    Pirates1
7         Sam Mendes  Christoph Waltz         6.8       200074175    Spectre1
8  Christopher Nolan        Tom Hardy         8.5       448130642         The

df1 = df.groupby(["Actor_1"]).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 3)
print (df1)

        Director      Actor_1  IMDB_Score  Gross_Earnings Movie_Title
0  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847      Avatar
1  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar1
2  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar2
3  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar3
```

Or faster solution:

```
nofilms =  df.groupby(["Actor_1"])['Movie_Title'].transform('size')
df1 = df[nofilms > 3]
print (df1)
        Director      Actor_1  IMDB_Score  Gross_Earnings Movie_Title
0  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847      Avatar
1  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar1
2  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar2
3  James Cameron  CCH Pounder         7.9       760505847     Avatar3
```

Then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
df2 = df1.groupby('Actor_1')['Gross_Earnings'].mean()
print (df2)
Actor_1
CCH Pounder    760505847
Name: Gross_Earnings, dtype: int64
```

And last plot by [`Series.plot.barh`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.barh.html):

```
df2.plot.barh()
```

Comment: Not quite - "Movie_Title" will always return one as they are all unique. I need the count of the actor to be > 4, then if this is True, return the average IMDB_Score - hope that makes sense?

Comment: Dont worry, you can change `'Movie_Title` to `Director`, output is same. Only transfome need any column of df.

Comment: Glad can help! Nice weekend!